# Парсинг XML средствами C#

Tags: c#, xml, синтаксический-анализ

Есть XML файл вида:

```
<tree>
   <name>Берёза</name>
   <age>3</age>
   <node>
       <name>Лист1</name>
       <age>1</age>
   </node>
   <node>
       <name>Лист2</name>
       <age>1</age>
   </node>
   <tree>
      <name>Персик</name>
      <age>3</age>
      <node>
         <name>Лист11</name>
         <age>1</age>
      </node>
      <node>
         <name>Лист22</name>
         <age>1</age>
      </node>
   </tree>
</tree>
```

Как пройтись по документу и заполнить структуры вида:

```
struct tree
{
   int name;
   int age
}
struct node
{
  int name;
  int age;
}

tree  t;
node n;
if (<tree>)
  t.name = name;
  t.age = age;
else
   n.name = name;
   n.age = age;
```

Comment: 1. Каким вы себе представляете результат, если ваши структуры никак не соотносятся с иерархией в XML? 2. Как вы собираетесь присваивать значения приватным полям?

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали и что именно не получается? В данном виде это не вопрос, а задание - не совсем формат данного сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Таким образом, http://ideone.com/Y8KOgr.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class node
{
    public string name;

    public string age;
}

public class tree
{
    public string name;

    public int age;

    [XmlElement("node")]
    public List<node> nodes;

    [XmlElement("tree")]
    public List<tree> trees;
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?> ...";

        var reader = new StringReader(xml);
        var result = (tree)new XmlSerializer(typeof (tree)).Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb387087.aspx. Олег Кныш прав, специально для этого есть LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать LINQ to XML. Очень удобная штука.
Вот статья на эту тему http://habrahabr.ru/post/24673/